# Como editar a identação no VSCode (quantidade de espaço por Tab)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Gostaria de saber como eu edito a **quantidade de espaço** que um TAB dá no Vscode.

Meu Vscode quando aperto a tecla tab, está dando 2 espaços ao invés de 1 (acho que apertei algo sem querer e modifiquei as configurações, pois antes ele dava apenas 1 espaço).
**Preciso que ele volte a dar somente 1 espaço quando aperto o tab.**

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

[image: A imagem abaixo mostra os 2 espaços que dá ao apertar tab somente 1x]

Comment: Está na barra de status, no canto inferior direito

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigada pela ajuda! Eu realmente não sabia que era tão simples.

Answer (score 1):

Vai em File > Preferences > Settings

Depois altera a propriedade "Tab size", está na aba "Text Editor" ou  "Commonly Used", você pode também, na barra de pesquisa da janela "Settings" digitar "Tab size".

O número é a quantidade de espaços que o Tab terá.

Comment: Muito Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Como um complemento para a resposta de @Rogerio Santos, você pode também editar no próprio settings.json do VSCode.

`CTRL + SHIFT + P` e pesquise 'User Settings Json' e clique enter, daí basta adicionar `"editor.tabSize": x` no final do documento, sendo x o valor que você deseja.

Pergunta do StackOverflow em inglês que me refiro: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972396/how-can-i-customize-the-tab-to-space-conversion-factor)

Answer (score -1):

Se vc olhar no canto inferior direito tem essa opção

[image: Espaços referentes a indentação do arquivo atual]

mas ela só funciona localmente, para o arquivo em questão

a resposta do amigo

> Vai em File > Preferences > Settings
> Depois altera a propriedade "Tab size", está na aba "Text Editor" ou "Commonly Used", você pode também, na barra de pesquisa da janela "Settings" digitar "Tab size".
> O número é a quantidade de espaços que o Tab terá.
> ~Rogerio Santos
> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468556/283641

é para tornar isso **permanente**, mas pelo que testei, apenas para arquivos novos, os antigos não foram editados

depois que mudar a configuração localmente (no arquivo) vc ainda precisara corrigir a indentação, para isso vc pode usar o comando **"CTRL+SHIFT+P"** e digitar no campo que apareceu **"reindent lines"** (apenas uma parte do comando já o exibira por completo) e basta apertar enter
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
ou ainda utilizar o comando **"ALT+SHIFT+F"**